# What's wrong with this class C++ declaration?

Tags: c++, class

My Professor gave us this class and told us that it won't compile. He says that the donors array would conflict with the constructor. So... why would that be?

I think that the name of the `Donor` array might do it, but it shouldn't be the problem because the name of the member array `donor` is case sensitive, and is therefore different than the class name.

Here's the code:

```
#ifndef DONORS_H
#define DONORS_H

#include <string>

#include "name.h"
#include "donor.h"

using namespace std;

const int 
    DONORS_LOAD_ERROR = 1,
    DONORS_UPDATE_ERROR = 2,
    DONORS_ADD_ERROR = 3;

const int MAX_DONORS = 100;

class Donors {
public:
    Donors() : size(0) {}
    void load(string filename);
    int getSize() {return size;}
    int find(Name name);
    int add(Name name);
    int add(Name name, Donation donation, int ytd);
    void processDonation(Name name, Donation donation);
    void update(string filename);
    void print();
private:
    Donor donorsList[MAX_DONORS];
    int size;
};

#endif
```

The professor writes:

> In this version, we've taken version 2, added constructors, and maximized the use of objects.

HOWEVER, the introduction of constructors breaks the declaration of the array data member inside the Donors class;
therefore THIS VERSION DOES NOT COMPILE!!!!

I've been discussing this with a classmate and we're both stumped. What's up with this C++ class?

**Edit:**

The compiler messages are shown below:

[image: Compiler Error]

It just occurred to me that the Donor class has a constructor. Being that we haven't touched vectors with a ten foot pole, how on earth are we supposed to compile this?

**Edit2:**

Here's the donor class:

```
#ifndef DONOR_H
#define DONOR_H

#include "name.h"
#include "donation.h"

using namespace std;

class Donor {
public:
    Donor(Name n, Donation ld=Donation(0, 0), int y=0) : name(n), lastDonation(ld), ytd(y) {}
    Name getName() {return name;}
    Donation getLastDonation() {return lastDonation;}
    int getYtd() {return ytd;}
    void processDonation(Donation d);
private:
    Name name;  
    Donation lastDonation;
    int ytd;
};

#endif
```

Comment: "Does not compile" is not sufficient error description, you know.

Comment: What error message did you get when you tried to compile it?

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: Since you don't provide an error message, I voted to close that as not a real question.

Comment: we also need to see the declaration of the `Donor` class

Comment: One day, I too would love to "maximise the use of objects".

Comment: @Moshe: just add `Name n=""` to the `Donor` constructor, and problem solved.  (Assuming `Name` is constructable from `const char(&)[N]` or `const char*`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difficult to say without the definition of the `Donor` class, but my guess is that he added a constructor with parameters to the `Donor` class, so it won't have the implicit default constructor any more.

But now, without a default constructor, that is a constructor that can be called without arguments, you cannot declare an array of such type, because there is no way to pass on the required parameters!

Comment: Your hunch was right: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2990667#2990667.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the class `Donor` (which you didn't include) doesn't have a default constructor. If so, you will get a compiler error because this line:

```
Donor donorsList[MAX_DONORS];
```

Will try to use the constructor-with-no-parameters that `Donor` doesn't have.

It will help you to do better in the course if you experience the errors your instructor is showing you. Then when you experience them in real life you will recognize them. If you're going to learn C++, the strategy of "me and a friend looked at this and it should compile fine" is never going to be a substitute for trying to compile it and seeing what errors you get.

Comment: Your hunch was right: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2990667#2990667.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the definition of `class Donor`.

From the looks of it, I would guess that `class Donor` has a non-default constructor, i. e. the constructor that takes one or more parameters.  In that case, the default constructor for `class Donor` is not generated by the compiler, and you have to define it yourself.

The default constructor is needed to create `donorsList`, because when you create an array of objects, the default constructor is called for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Considering first `Donors` class:

```
#ifndef DONORS_H
#define DONORS_H

#include <string>

#include "name.h"
#include "donor.h"
```

OK so far.

```
using namespace std;
```

**No!** Never put `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header. The author (your professor) is almost guaranteeing silly name clashes like the compiler complaining about `distance` in some poor user’s code.

```
const int 
    DONORS_LOAD_ERROR = 1,
    DONORS_UPDATE_ERROR = 2,
    DONORS_ADD_ERROR = 3;

const int MAX_DONORS = 100;
```

Those are bad names. Reserve shouting ALL UPPERCASE for macro names. But do use them for macro names.

Also, better use an `enum` for such constants.

And also, better use exceptions for failure reporting.

```
class Donors {
public:
    Donors() : size(0) {}
    void load(string filename);
```

The `string` argument would better be passed by reference to `const`.

```
    int getSize() {return size;}
```

This method should be `const`.

Also, while the prefix `get` has a practical advantage in some languages like Java and C#, which support instrospection (and hence tools based on introspection), in C++ it's just silly verbosity – in most cases, and in this case.

Better call that mathod just `name`.

Guideline: think about the readability of the calling code.

```
    int find(Name name);
```

The `name` argument would probably better be passed as reference to `const`.

```
    int add(Name name);
```

The `name` argument would probably better be passed as reference to `const`.

```
    int add(Name name, Donation donation, int ytd);
```

The `name` and `donation` arguments would probably better be passed as references to `const`.

The name `ytd` is very bad. It is very difficult to guess what it means.

```
    void processDonation(Name name, Donation donation);
```

The `name` and `donation` arguments would probably better be passed as references to `const`.

The interface is ambiguous: what is the difference between `add` and `process`?

```
    void update(string filename);
```

The `name` argument would probably better be passed as reference to `const`.

The name of this method is bad.

It is nearly impossible to guess what this method does.

```
    void print();
```

Where exactly should this method print something, and in what format?

```
private:
    Donor donorsList[MAX_DONORS];
```

This declaration requires that `Donor` has a constructor that can be called without arguments, a **default constructor**.

```
    int size;
};

#endif
```

---

Considering the second `Donor` class:

```
#ifndef DONOR_H
#define DONOR_H

#include "name.h"
#include "donation.h"
```

OK so far.

```
using namespace std;
```

**No!** Never put `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header. The author (your professor) is almost guaranteeing silly name clashes like the compiler complaining about `distance` in some poor user’s code.

```
class Donor {
public:
    Donor(Name n, Donation ld=Donation(0, 0), int y=0) : name(n), lastDonation(ld), ytd(y) {}
```

`y` and `ytd` are bad names. It is impossible to guess at this point what they’re about.

`ld` is a bad name.

The `Name` and `Donation` arguments should probably better be passed by reference to `const`.

Note: when there is a user-declared constructor, such as the one above, then *a default constructor is not generated automatically*.

```
    Name getName() {return name;}
```

This method should be `const`.

Also, while the prefix `get` has a practical advantage in some languages like Java and C#, which support instrospection (and hence tools based on introspection), in C++ it's just silly verbosity – in most cases, and in this case.

Better call that mathod just `name`.

Guideline: think about the readability of the calling code.

```
    Donation getLastDonation() {return lastDonation;}
```

See comments above.

```
    int getYtd() {return ytd;}
```

See comments above.

```
    void processDonation(Donation d);
```

The argument should probably better be passed by reference to `const`.

```
private:
    Name name;  
    Donation lastDonation;
    int ytd;
};

#endif
```

---

In short, the `Donors` class requires that `Donor` has a default constructor, but since `Donor` has a user-declared constructor a default constructor is not generated.

One fix is to replace the simple array with a `std::vector` or other collection, e.g.

```
std::vector<Donor> donors_;
```

or

```
std::map< std::string, Donor > donors_;
```

Comment: `Donors` is a container of `Donor` objects I think.

Comment: Oh, subtle difference in the names. I didn't see that. Lemme fix the answer. OK, done.